# Finding a string in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to check if the string `NAME` is present in an active cell, and if it is present, the program should ignore the cell. If not present, then that cell's contents must be deleted. This is the code I have:

```
Sub Search()

    Range("B3").Select
    If ActiveCell.Find(What:="NAME") = False Then ActiveCell.Clear

End Sub
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. As you can see, I'm just checking cell B3 for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what kind of match you are trying to find. So what are you trying to find? A complete match? A partial match? A case sensitive match?

A) **Complete Match + Case Sensitive**

In such a case the cell value has to be just `"NAME"`. Instances like `"   NaMe"`, `"NAme"`, `"name"` etc will not be matched.

```
If ActiveCell.Value <> "NAME" Then ActiveCell.ClearContents
```

B) **Complete Match + Not Case Sensitive**

```
If UCase(ActiveCell.Value) <> "NAME" Then ActiveCell.ClearContents
```

or

```
If LCase(ActiveCell.Value) <> "name" Then ActiveCell.ClearContents
```

In such a case the cell value has to be `"NAME"` or `"NaMe"` etc. Instances like `"   NaMe"`, `"Surname"` etc will not be matched.

C) **Partial Match + Case Sensitive**

```
If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "NAME") = 0 Then ActiveCell.ClearContents
```

In such a case the cell value must contain `"NAME"`. For example `NAME GAME`. `SURNAME` etc. Instances like `"My Name is Sid"`, `"What's in a NAMe"` etc will not be matched.

D) **Partial Match + Not Case Sensitive**

```
If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "NAME", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ActiveCell.ClearContents
```

In such a case the cell value must contain `"NAME"`. The `Case` doesn't matter. For example `NAME GAME`,  `SURNAme`, `"My Name is Sid"`, `"What's in a NAMe"` etc.

Here is an snapshot of different scenarios.

[image]

**Note**: If you want to use `.FIND` then see [THIS LINK](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). Based on the above scenarios, you will have to play with

1. `LookAt:=` which can take `xlPart` or `xlWhole` as one of it's arguments.
2. `MatchCase:=` which can take  `True` or `False` as one of it's arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you would like it to?:

```
Sub Search()
   Range("B3").Activate
    If ActiveCell.Value = "NAME" = False Then ActiveCell.Clear
End Sub
```

Note, is case sensitive and looks for the entire cell's content rather than a string within a cell.

Comment: + 1 . I think the user actually wants `ClearContents` rather then `Clear` :)